# C# beginner - Callback in the same function

Tags: c#

I'm pretty sure that is possible (at least in java it is) and I'm C# beginner.

So I have a function which includes a callback (notify some other method that some work is finished).

I don't want to call another function because I'm losing a parameter there (and can't pass parameters in callback functions). How can I do everything in the same function?

What I'm doing now:

```
public static Tween Play(Tween tweenToPlay) 
{
    return tweenToPlay.Play().OnComplete(RewindCallback);

}

private static void RewindCallback() 
{
    // Execute some code after Tween is completed
}
```

What I actually want:

```
public static Tween Play(Tween tweenToPlay) 
{
    return tweenToPlay.Play().OnComplete(/*Create a function that will execute here*/);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just want an anonymous method?

```
public static Tween Play(Tween tweenToPlay) 
{
    return tweenToPlay.Play().OnComplete(() => 
    {
        //... your code
    });
}
```

Comment: Nine whole seconds!

Comment: Great that's it! I can see this is also called lambda expression? What is the difference between anonymous method and lambda expression?

Comment: lambda expression is basically a `Func<TResult>` or `Action<T>` which are generic delegates while anonymous method is just  a method with no name

Comment: Hmm, [here's an essay on the distinction between lambda expressions and anonymous methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/01/10/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-one.aspx). I'm trying to make sense out of it at the moment. Anything that author writes is worth reading.

Comment: brilliant!! using lamdas

Answer (score 14):

Do you mean a lambda expression, like this?

```
public static Tween Play(Tween tweenToPlay) 
{
    return tweenToPlay
        .Play()
        .OnComplete(() => {
            //  Do stuff
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous/lambdas are shorter to write, but depending on the complexity - you might want to use a full fledged class as follows.

Create a class with a field for that variable and an appropriate callback function.

When you want to subscribe to the callback - create an instance of that class with that field set, and set the callback to the callback in that instance.

Example:

```
class Temp
{
    public Tween Tween1;

    public void RewindCallback()
    {
        // Execute some code after Tween is completed
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
Temp temp;
public Tween Play(Tween tweenToPlay)
{
    temp = new Temp { Tween1 = tweenToPlay };
    return tweenToPlay.Play().OnComplete(temp.RewindCallback);
}
```